# how to temporarily disable a user's cronjobs?

Tags: cron

How do I temporarily disable one or more users' cron jobs? In particular, I do not want to suspend the user's cron rights - merely not fire any of their jobs.

I am on SLES 11 SP2 and SP3 systems

Comment: Can't you just use the `-u user` switch of the `crontab` command and put a `#` comment character in front of the jobs to disable for the given user?

Comment: @Janis then I need to keep track of what the user (there are many) had already commented out, plus the user can go ahead and add another thing in (I am not adding them to /etc/cron.deny). Too much manual work :(

Comment: Dinesh, I (mis-)understood you want a fine-granular control about what you disable.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

(Note that this answer was written in the days before systemd. I haven't checked how systemd's version of cron behaves in this scenario.)

`touch /var/spool/cron/crontabs/$username; chmod 0 /var/spool/cron/crontabs/$username` should do the trick. Restore with `chmod 600` and `touch` (you need to change the file's mtime to make cron (attempt to) reload it).

On at least Debian and probably with Vixie cron in general, `chmod 400 /var/spool/cron/crontabs/$username` also does the trick, because that implementation insists on permissions being exactly 600. However this only lasts until the user runs the `crontab` command.

If you want a robust way, I don't think there's anything better than temporarily moving their crontab out of the way or changing the permissions, *and* temporarily adding them to `/etc/cron.deny`.

Comment: Thanks. On my system it is /var/spool/cron/tabs/$username. But it still executes, even after the `chmod`.

Comment: After changing the file perms, I also needed to stop/restart cron. I thought its probably because cron might be holding the stuff in memory. So I added `touch $username` after the `chmod`. But that didn't help. (btw got your point on `cron.deny`)

Comment: @Dinesh Indeed you need to update the file's mtime or else cron thinks it hasn't changed and keeps cached information. I noticed this while testing yesterday but forgot to mention it in my answer, sorry about that.

Comment: If you want to disable for all standard users just: `chgrp root /var/spool/cron/crontabs`

Comment: This did not work for me in Ubuntu 20.04. Needed to `sudo systemctl restart cron.service` as @Dinesh said.

Comment: @FazleRabbi This answer is from before systemd, so it may not apply to modern Linux systems (apart from the non-systemd holdouts).

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' I see that now. thanks!

Answer (score 12):

How about something like this to disable a user crontab:

```
crontab -l -u [username] >/tmp/[username].cron.tmp
crontab -r -u [username]
```

and to re-enable:

```
crontab -u [username] /tmp/[username].cron.tmp
```

This has the added advantage that you can run it as that user without needing root (just take the -u parameter away).

Comment: Remember that `/tmp` is [cleared periodically](https://serverfault.com/a/377349/508737), and Murphy's law states that it *will* be cleared ~10 seconds before your re-enable command ;-)

Answer (score 9):

If you just want to stop all `cron` jobs entirely for a while -- for example, while doing system maintenance which they might interact badly with -- the commands are normally as follows:

```
sudo systemctl stop crond.service
```

and, to resume

```
sudo systemctl start crond.service
```

Note however that some systems use `cron.service` instead of `crond.service`; you can learn which it is as follows:

```bsh
$ systemctl list-units --type=service | grep cron
```

Overkill for the specific question posed, but provides "one-stop shopping" and doesn't require playing with the filesystem or temporary files. Also for small embedded systems (Raspberry Pi, Beagle Bone, etc etc, etc) with a single user account.

Comment: Since this disables cron for all users, it doesn’t really answer the question.

Comment: @Scott: The OP's question states, "one or more users". This method can be quite useful on small-ish embedded systems. IMHO it doesn't deserve a downvote.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following like so:

```
crondisable
cronenable

crondisable some_other_user
...
```

The `zsh` code (put in your `.zshrc`):

```
ecerr () {
print -r -- "$@" >&2
}
crondisable() {
        local user="${1:-$(whoami)}"
        local cronpath="/tmp/$user.cron.tmp"
        test -e "$cronpath" && {
        ecerr "There is already a disabled crontab at $cronpath. Remove that manually if you want to proceed."
        return 1
        }
        crontab -l -u $user > "$cronpath"
        crontab -r -u $user
}
cronenable() {
        local user="${1:-$(whoami)}"
        local cronpath="/tmp/$user.cron.tmp"
        test -e "$cronpath" || {
        ecerr "No disabled cron at $cronpath"
        return 1
        }
        crontab -u $user "$cronpath"
        mv "$cronpath" "${cronpath}.bak"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use

```
crontab -l | sed '/^\s*[0-9\*]/s/^/#---inserted-by-my-script---/' | crontab
```

and for re-activation

```
crontab -l | sed 's/^\#---inserted-by-my-script---//'| crontab
```

The first line adds `#---inserted-by-my-script---` in front of every line with active crontabs, the second line just removes it again.
The problem using a temp copy and then do `crontab -r` is: you can't use it twice. If you remove your crontab and overwrite the existing temp copy of your crontab accidently with the empty one, you don't have a backup.

Answer (score -1):

I agree, the path via systemctl is the one to take.
On raspberry, toe comands would be

```
sudo systemctl stop cron.service
sudo systemctl start cron.service
```

Comment: This will stop the entire `cron` service. The OP wanted to be able to choose which users' crontabs to disable.

Comment: @roaima: Your comment is correct of course, but I imagine that some people wind up here after using a search term such as `linux suspend cron job temporarily`, and some of those that do may find this answer ([and the one above](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/407901/286615)) quite useful. I wonder if the question `how to temporarily disable all user's cronjobs?` would be classified as a duplicate?